# Layout Page is not rendered in my view though I have inserted @{ Layout="~/Views/_LayoutPage.cshtml";} in my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My Controller Action is like this:

```
public ActionResult AdminDetails()
{
    return View("~/Views/ConfigLocation/Admin.cshtml");
}
```

And My View is like below:

```
<link href=".../>
<head>
<link>....
</head>
@{
    ViewBag.Title="";
}
@{
    Layout="~/Views/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
}

<div>
  Some html conntent..
</div>
```

But I am not able to get Layout Page in my view. please help me.Iam a beginner in mvc

Comment: Does your _LayoutPage reside in the location of "~/Views/_LayoutPage.cshtml"? Does it not maybe sit in the shared folder? Maybe show a picture/capture of your solution explorer with the _LayoutPage

Comment: Is the directory path correct? Is the layout here? Check pls.

Comment: @monstertjie_zaYes The layout page sits inside view.

Comment: @codelover  The directory path is correct.